# SVG and keyframes not drawing letters fully

Tags: html, css, svg

When playing around with some SVG animation, i ran into a strange artifact. When rendering keystroke-dashoffset animations in Chrome (haven't tested any other browsers) stops before they are finished, see below. In this case it is the S and M.

The lines also seem to retract a bit in the beginning. How do i fix this so that the letters render fully?

I use OSX El Capitan and Chrome v.51.0.2704.84.

Here is the code (not written by me):

```css
text {
  font-family: sans-serif;

  stroke-dasharray: 100%;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100%;

  -webkit-animation: draw 8s forwards;
     -moz-animation: draw 8s forwards;
       -o-animation: draw 8s forwards;
      -ms-animation: draw 8s forwards;
          animation: draw 8s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="150">
  <text x="100" y="80" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" font-size="50">Some text</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can't see any problems (latest Chrome 52.0 dev-m). I am on Win 10.

Comment: What operating system do you use? I use OSX El Capitan and Chrome v.51.0.2704.84

Comment: Can confirm that it does work on Windows 10. (Cool effect by the way!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the `stroke-dasharray` property in CSS. Setting this to a value larger than 100% (125% is enough for most fonts) will draw the letters correctly. This will cause the letters to already be drawn when the animation starts, so i set the `stroke-dashoffset` property to 125%, too.

```css
body {
  background:black;
}
text {
  font-family: initial;

  stroke-dasharray: 125%;
  stroke-dashoffset: 125%;

  -webkit-animation: draw 5s ease-in-out forwards;
     -moz-animation: draw 5s ease-in-out forwards;
       -o-animation: draw 5s ease-in-out forwards;
      -ms-animation: draw 5s ease-in-out forwards;
          animation: draw 5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes draw {
 100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
<svg width="500" height="150">
  <text x="100" y="80" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" font-size="50">Some text</text>
</svg>
```